# what does "how smooth f is" mean?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

When a question states that "how smooth is $f~$" what should I do? For example how can we apply it in this question :

Consider the function $f: R\rightarrow R$ defined by

$   f(x) =
\begin{cases}x^{2}\sin⁡(1/x^2 ) & ~~\text {if}~~ x≠0;\\ 0 & ~~\text{if}~~ x=0; \end{cases}$

How smooth is $f$ ? What should I do? Is green theorem related to these kind of questions?

Comment: [Smooth function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}x^{2}\sin⁡(1/x^2 ) & ~~\text {if}~~ x≠0;\\ 0 & ~~\text{if}~~ x=0; \end{cases}$$

$$f'(x) =
\begin{cases} 2x\sin⁡(1/x^2 ) - \frac{\cos(1/x^2 )}{x} & ~~\text {if}~~ x≠0;\\ 0 & ~~\text{if}~~ x=0; \end{cases}$$

If you see the graph, [image: Smoothness Graph], the function is clearly not continuous at x=0.

For more details on how to proceed, check [this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_function#Examples)

Answer (score 6):

It means that you should investigate the following:

Is $f$ continuous? Is $f$ differentiable? If $f$ is differentiable, then is the derivate $f'$ a continuous (or differentiable) function? If $f'$ is differentiable, then what about $f''$? Etc.

No Green's theorem that I know of is even remotely related to this.